# .ts files always get recognized as text/vnd.trolltech.linguist and never as video/mp2t

Tags: http, video-streaming, mime-types

I am streaming some HTTP Live Stream from Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.3. At the client side, when i do the Wireshark trace, i always get the video file ts as text/vnd.trolltech.linguist and never as video/mp2t.

IF i stream the same content with the Windows IIS server, i get the video/mp2t.

I am not if there is any requirement of changing the Apache MIME configuration so it streams the correct data type?

Can anyone suggest some quick-fix for the same?

I have found that some patch has been released for Ubuntu for this issue but i don't see anything for RHEL.

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shared-mime-info/+bug/502642) bugreport might help you. Seems like the .ts file extension had an old meaning...

Answer (score 1):

For someone else who arrive to this page pinned first on Google engine and on StackOverflow after put "text/vnd.trolltech.linguist" ( in my case becasue Facebook say "text/vnd.trolltech.linguist is not allowed" when trying to upload TS file), you can try to change the extension file to ".MTS" or ".M2TS" , following the recommendation posted on the forum given by Wil Macaulay

> .MTS and .M2TS file extensions should resolve to mime type video/MP2T

that work for me.
Hope this helps :-)